# Matching Columns by Neighbourhood

Tags: microsoft-excel

I had a recent post trying to solve a similar problem, but redefining the problem (as I will in this post) will still let me get to where I need to be, so I apologize if this is redundant.

In the attached image, I am currently trying to match those 3 columns by their shared neighbourhood name. I have currently done a few of the matches manually to illustrate the desired effect I wish to have.  The first 16 rows have been manually aligned to show what I need to accomplish.  The remainder of the rows reflect the raw date.

Other than going about this process manually, I do not know how I can align the columns in this manner.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: you would like a given name in column `A` to be on the same row if it also appears in columns `B` and/or `C`?

Comment: this is this question that you posted 2 hours ago, with an adjustment for your implicit XY problem https://superuser.com/questions/1411623/aggregating-columns-by-neighbourhood-and-quarters

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t see what you want to do. You show *one* screenshot! What’s input and what’s output?  Please describe it in sentences, and give clear examples of input and output (or before and after, if you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

Take the column your list of Quarter 1 neighborhoods is in, copy the entire thing. Go to the next worksheet, paste it in column `A` there. Then copy the entire list of Q2 neighborhoods, copy that, paste it below the first list in column `A` on your new sheet. Do the same for each list of neighborhoods.

Once you've copied every list into column `A` in your new sheet, select that column. Go to the Data tab. Find 'Remove Duplicates'. Hit 'OK'. Then sort that column alphabetically.

Now you have your master list.

Given that this is another attempt to solve a smaller problem than your actual problem (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1411623/aggregating-columns-by-neighbourhood-and-quarters) you posted 2 hrs ago):

I still don't understand how you intend to sum across, since the input lists are still going to be incomplete. You also haven't told us where the data is coming from, so I doubt that any answer that *does* properly answer *this* question will actually help you much.

I suggest that you start by reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Then delete this question, and the previous one, and write a new question that describes what you actually have and what you need to actually do.

Comment: I will post another one, similar title, and be far more specific after reading that link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you've manually done about the first 15 rows or so and left the rest to illustrate what the raw data looks like.  Here's a way to do it using a pivot table as a helper to extract the unique list of all values as a first step.  I'll show most of the pivot table steps just for illustration, but recognize that while it looks like a bunch of steps, they're trivial and require just a few mouse clicks.  It will get you to this:

[image]

Columns A:C contain the raw data.  The pivot table is in E:F and can be hidden so you don't see it.  The result is in columns G:I.  For illustration, I aligned those with the pivot table rows, but that isn't necessary.

**The pivot table**

[image]

You select `Multiple consolidation ranges` and tell it where to stick the output.  Click on `Select ranges`.

[image]

Select `Create a single page field for me`, and `Next`.

[image]

Specify or select the entire data range.  Click `Add` and `Finish`.

[image]

You're back to the first screen.  Click `OK`.

[image]

Drag Value to the `Rows` window.  Right-click on `Row` and select `Remove field`.  You can close that dialog window.

[image]

You get a table that looks like this.  Some quick cleanup.

[image]

Use the pulldown arrow and deselect `Blank`.  Right-click on the Grand Totals and Qtr columns (you may need to do just Qtr3), and delete those.  You're left with the unique list shown in the first image.

**The results**

Copy the column headings.  The formula in G4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$6,MATCH($E4,A$2:A$6,0),COLUMN()-6),"")
```

Copy it across and down to populate all of the columns and rows of the results.  This uses the pivot table's list of unique values, looks for each pivot table value in each data column, and displays it in the results row if it is there for the quarter, or blank if not.  The `COLUMN()-6` just translates the location of the results columns to the raw data columns (my results columns are 6 columns to the right of the corresponding data columns).

This looks like a lot of steps, but it only takes a few minutes to get from raw data to the result.

### Alternate Method

If you don't want to use a pivot table, you can generate the unique list with an array formula.  This is shown in columns K:N below:

[image]

The formula in K2:

```
{=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($A$2:$C$6<>"")*(COUNTIF($K$1:K1,$A$2:$C$6)=0),ROW($2:$6)*100+COLUMN($A:$C),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""}
```

This is an array formula, so confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Once you enter the first formula, you can just copy and paste to populate the rest of the column.  Rather than reinvent the wheel and figure out the formula from scratch, I shamelessly adapted it from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1966-excel-extract-unique-values-from-multiple-columns.html) (actually, that link also has essentially the same pivot table explanation, and their images may be a better match to Excel because I used a different application).  Again, you can hide the list in column K.

The formula in L2 is the same as the previous results formula, just adjusted for location:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$6,MATCH($K2,A$2:A$6,0),COLUMN()-11),"")
```

Comment: This solution you provided is exactly what I had in mind, but I wasn't able to articulate it. I can FINALLY rest easy now that I have this.